# Android webview insert custom String value in Input box

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I like to pass string value into my webview inbut box when image onclick. there is no edit text in my android

```
 webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 ImageView imgClick = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 final String mText = "shortcode1";


 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebviewUrl());
 webview.loadUrl("http://sitewithinputbox.html");

            imgClick.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
                    if(keyCode == event.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                        //How can i Do it
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

I added imageview under webview .. I need onclick image insert image Short code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JavaScript code that simply finds the text element and sets its value. To call the JavaScript you can use `evaluateJavascript` or call `loadUrl` with your JavaScript code. `evaluateJavascript` only works with KitKat and above and it has callback if you need to return a value from the script:

```
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            webview.evaluateJavascript(script, 
                new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String result) {
                    }
                });
        else
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:"+script);
```

An example script may look like this:

```
(function() {
    var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");

    var text1 = formElement.elements["text1"];

    text1.value = 'SET YOUR VALUE HERE';
})();
```

Comment: where i insert this? setOnKeyListener?